# How to left-justify paragraphs and remove hyphenation from Sphinx's PDF output

Tags: python-sphinx

By default, Latex fully justified paragraphs and perform hyphenation throughout. I find it very hard to read long and fully justified texts.
I find it easier to read shorter texts which are left justified.

How do you achieve the following?

1. Make font size for body text bigger but keep font size for source code small
2. Remove hyphenation
3. Left-justify all texts

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of working on Sphinx and self-discovery from testing and search, I managed to find the solution. I would like to share here.

In the `conf.py` file, you may add the following entries for `latex_elements` keyword:

```
latex_elements = {
    'papersize': 'a4paper',
    'pointsize': '12pt',
    'preamble': r'''
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    '''
}
```

However, this will make source code lines wrap. In order to use small font size for code, you need to add the following lines at the top of `conf.py`.

```
# -- To change font size for code alone
from sphinx.highlighting import PygmentsBridge
from pygments.formatters.latex import LatexFormatter

class CustomLatexFormatter(LatexFormatter):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        super(CustomLatexFormatter, self).__init__(**options)
        # Available font size is found in 
        # https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Built-in_sizes
        self.verboptions = r"formatcom=\scriptsize"

PygmentsBridge.latex_formatter = CustomLatexFormatter
```

Comment: did you try [this](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html#the-sphinxsetup-interface): ``'sphinxsetup': 'verbatimwrapslines=false',`` in `latex_elements`,  and also ``'fvset': r'\fvset{fontsize=\scriptsize}',`` also in `latex_elements`. And, please document which Sphinx version number you are with.